# Foreign key creation

Tags: mysql, sql

I am having some trouble adding a foreign key constraint to a table in my MySQL-database.

I have the following **user** table:

```
CREATE TABLE `user` (
   `Id` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
   `Email` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
   `EmailConfirmed` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
   `PasswordHash` longtext,
   `SecurityStamp` longtext,
   `PhoneNumber` longtext,
   `PhoneNumberConfirmed` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
   `TwoFactorEnabled` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
   `LockoutEndDateUtc` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
   `LockoutEnabled` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
   `AccessFailedCount` int(11) NOT NULL,
   `UserName` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`Id`)
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

And this is my usernotice table I'm trying to add a foreign key to:

```
CREATE TABLE `usernotice` (
   `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   `notifySitemap` bit(1) NOT NULL,
   `notifyRobots` bit(1) NOT NULL,
   `user_id` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
   `health_site_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
   KEY `user_constraint_idx` (`user_id`),
   KEY `healthSiteId_idx` (`health_site_id`),
   CONSTRAINT `healthSiteId` FOREIGN KEY (`health_site_id`) REFERENCES `health_site` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

I'm trying to reference the user.id column in the usernotice.user_id column. To do this I'm using the following SQL:

```
ALTER TABLE usernotice
ADD CONSTRAINT userId
  FOREIGN KEY (user_id)
  REFERENCES user (Id)
  ON DELETE NO ACTION
  ON UPDATE NO ACTION;
```

When I execute this I get an error with a 1215 code. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

**EDIT:** After inspecting the `show create table` querys I noticed a difference in the charset used. Recreating the `usernotice` table with another charset fixed this.

Comment: Is `user.id` the primary key? What does 1215 code mean?

Comment: Yes, `user.id` is the primary key. The MySQL manual states that 1215 is: `Error: 1215 SQLSTATE: HY000 (ER_CANNOT_ADD_FOREIGN)

Message: Cannot add foreign key constraint`

Comment: in that case you `usernotice` table should be empty

Comment: The `usernotice` table is empty.

Comment: Please show the output of "show create table user" and "show create table usernotice".

Comment: Is `Id` a primary key in your `users` table?

Comment: @slaakso I have updated the question with the SQL-querys for creation.

Comment: try execute without `CONSTRAINT userId`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html Corresponding columns in the foreign key and the referenced key must have similar data types. The size and sign of integer types must be the same. The length of string types need not be the same. For nonbinary (character) string columns, the character set and collation must be the same.

Your character sets are not the same...